# Populate table data with total days of month using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to populate total days in a month, in `<td>` when document loads, right now only first rows data is filled with `total days in a month`, how i can fill each row with total days.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >Days in Month</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="here">Days:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="here">Days:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="here">Days:</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**jquery:**

```
var down = document.getElementById('here');
           function daysInMonth (month, year) {
               return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
           }

        $(document).ready(function(){
               var date = new Date();
               var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
               var year = date.getFullYear();
               down.innerHTML = daysInMonth(month, year);
           });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattii/4b9c2oqn/3/)

Comment: You're not supposed to use the same `id` for multiple elements. Use a `class` instead, or some other selector. jQuery has `.each()`, which you can use here to address each `<td>` in turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what your looking for ?

```js
// var down = document.getElementById('here');
           function daysInMonth (month, year) {
               return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
           }

        $(document).ready(function(){
               var date = new Date();
               var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
               var year = date.getFullYear();
               //down.innerHTML = daysInMonth(month, year);
               $(".here").text(daysInMonth(month, year));
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >Days in Month</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Days:<span class="here"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Days:<span class="here"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Days:<span class="here"></span></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

(I've used `<span class="here"></span>` instead of multiple `id` on `<td>` : `id` should be unique)

(also you don't need to use `document.getElementBySomething` as you're using jQuery)